# How do I filter messages that are sent to a single recipient?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-groups

I am receiving emails that has been copied to a several email addresses. For example, an email is copied to `engineering.myorg@gmail.com` and `marketing.myorg@gmail.com` and I have subscribed to these two email groups; hence I am getting these emails. And there are some other emails those are only sent to `marketing.myorg@gmail.com`.

Let's say that I have created two filters, and some email belong to both of these groups. I need to filter the emails that exclusively are sent to `marketing.myorg@gmail.com` to delete those at once.

How can I do this?

Note: The actual mail groups are in format of mail-group@myorg.com; because, our organization is using gmail application for email.

Comment: Create a filter for marketing.myorg@gmail.com that deletes everything and a filter for engineering.myorg@gmail.com that forwards to where ever you want? Obviously, test this before putting it into production use, it may not work.

Comment: The matter in this case, there is a chance that an email to be forwarded to both email groups. For example, a person sends an email to just marketing; and then another email copied to both engineering and marketing; and another email copied to all engineering, marketing and some other group called architecture. So, in my context, I am not very much interested in marketing stuff (I only read those mails rarely).So I need to filter all the emails that are exclusively being sent to marketing.If any email has cc'ed to any other group by any chance, that should not be there in this list.

Comment: If an email is sent to two of your addresses, does gmail treat it as two separate emails for filtering purposes? If so, my solution will work. If not, it won't. Anyone know for sure? I'm too lazy to test :)

Answer (score 1):

I think all you'll be able to do is filter messages that have one address but not the other.

```
 to:marketing.myorg@gmail.com -to: engineering.myorg@gmail.com
```

should find all messages sent to `marketing.myorg@gmail.com` but not also to `engineering.myorg@gmail.com`.

Comment: I actually tried this. When I had to exclude a few email addresses using this technique; it doesn't work as expected :(

Comment: Well, maybe you could put what you tried into your question and we can offer suggestions to improve it.